# Python: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: ''

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

Hey guys beginner coder here,

So I am getting this error:

```
self.scancode_dec_seriennummer_va = int(self.scancode_hex_seriennummer_va, 16)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: ''
```

This is a GUI application, so basically in the field i will give the following string which looks like this for example this value is entered by scanning the barcode with a barcode scanner:

```
61184#11AF0M000F6ED3A420
```

so basically my code splits this scancode and generates a serial number mac address etc.
by splitting it into pieces and then converts the split code(decimal) to hexadecimal thats how i get my serialnumber generated.

here is the code snippet:

```
    self.ui.lineEdit_SCGehauseVA.textChanged.connect(self.split_scancode_string_VA)

    def split_scancode_string_VA(self):
        self.scancode_gehause_va = self.ui.lineEdit_SCGehauseVA.text()
        self.scancode_gehause_mac_va = self.scancode_gehause_va[12:]
       
        self.scancode_gehause_artikel_va = self.scancode_gehause_va[:5]
         
        self.scancode_gehause_mac_va = ':'.join(self.scancode_gehause_mac_va[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(self.scancode_gehause_mac_va), 2))
        self.ui.lineEdit_MACVA.setText(self.scancode_gehause_mac_va)
        
        self.ui.ArtikelNummerlineEditlVA.setText(self.scancode_gehause_artikel_va)
        
        self.scancode_hex_seriennummer_va = self.scancode_gehause_va[14:]
        
        self.scancode_dec_seriennummer_va = int(self.scancode_hex_seriennummer_va, 16)        
        
        self.ui.lineEdit_SerienNummerVA.setText(int(self.scancode_dec_seriennummer_va))
```

Could one of you please help me with this, an example would be super helpful as well

Update:
When I do this, I get the following output:

```
pprint(self.scancode_hex_seriennummer_va)

''
''
''
''
''
''
''
''
''
''
''
''
''
''
''
''
''
''
'0'
'0F'
'0F9'
'0F9E'
'0F9ED'
'0F9EDB'
'0F9EDB8'
'0F9EDB8F'
'0F9EDB8F0'
'0F9EDB8F00'
```

i think i know what the problem is how do i get rid of everything except the last value '0F9EDB8F00'

Comment: The error is occurring because you have a blank `self.scancode_hex_serienummer_va`. Can you give an example input that failed? It likely has to do with the way you are parsing the input.

Comment: This ```0F9EDBA420``` would be an example of self.scancode_hex_serienummer_va which is actually the scancode that is entered by scanning the barcode. so basically:
self.scancode_gehause_va[14:] = 0F9EDBA420

Comment: OK. What would you expect the result to be in this case?

Comment: @Ramas I tested the code in your question with input `58184#99AF0M000F9EDBA420`, and it outputs `00:0F:9E:DB:A4:20`, `58184` and `67089703968` without any errors. So either you're running some different code, or `lineEdit_SCGehauseVA.text()` doesn't contain what you claim it does. What is the exact output of `print(repr(self.ui.lineEdit_SCGehauseVA.text()))`?

Comment: @ogdenkov iexpect the result to be the hexadecimal value of 0F9EDBA420 converted to 67089698560 which is a decimal value

Comment: @ekhumoro my code works fine when you have to copy paste 58184#99AF0M000F9EDBA420 but when i have to type it down then i get the error mentioned above

Comment: @Ramas Did you actually read my comment? I know that the code in the question works. Once again, please show the exact output of `print(repr(self.ui.lineEdit_SCGehauseVA.text()))`.

Comment: @ekhumoro sorry about that this is the exact output: '' Nothing else

Comment: @Ramas But what is the output *after scanning the barcode value into the line-edit* (i.e. not using copy/paste)? Also: how exactly is this value updated in your real application? Your latest edit to the question suggests it may sometimes consist of incomplete vales. In which case, the `textChanged` handler needs to check that the the current value has the correct length/format before attempting any further processing.

Comment: @ekhumoro i hope i dont piss you off here but what i get as the output after using the scanner on the lineedit is the following :
   self.scancode_dec_seriennummer_va = int((self.scancode_hex_seriennummer_va), 16)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: ''

I hope i have answered your question

Comment: @Ramas barcode scanners normally behave like virtual keyboards. You have to check for the validity of the string before converting it. If the barcode length is always the same, then just verify that, otherwise just `return` whenever the hex string is empty.

Comment: sorry @musicamante I am not sure what you mean really could you please give me an example. I know they work like virtual keyboards. but how exactly can i check for the validity of this string is there an in built function?

Comment: @Ramas As I already suggested: you could at least simply check the length of the input. So `if len(self.scancode_gehause_va) < 24: return` would be a reasonable start, no? Or perhaps use a regexp if the input has a consistent format.

Answer (score 0):

Given your example input that fails, `0F9EDBA420`, and that your code sets `self.scancode_hex_seriennummer_va = self.scancode_gehause_va[14:]`, this error occurs because `self.scancode_hex_seriennummer_va` is blank, i.e. `''`. Therefore `int('', 16)` fails.

Slicing a string with less than 15 characters with `[14:]` will return a blank string, which is invalid input to the `int()` function. For example

```
>>> mys = "0F9EDBA420"
>>> mys[14:]
''
>>> int(mys[14:])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: As mentioned before the actual string is "58184#99AF0M000F9EDBA420" this long but once sliced like you said is "0F9EDBA420" I also tried with [:16] still gives me the same error, would you know how to fix this?

Comment: You're right that `hex_str = "58184#99AF0M000F9EDBA420"; int(hex_str[14:], 16)` works fine. Somehow, though, you are getting a blank string for `self.scancode_hex_seriennummer_va`. That's what the error is message says. Are you sure you are getting the correct input from `self.scancode_gehause_va = self.ui.lineEdit_SCGehauseVA.text()`?

Comment: I think I am getting the correct input, as said before this is a gui application so when i set my cursor on the field use the barcode scanner to scan the barcode the error pops up. BUT! when i copy paste the same hex string then it works fine.
I am googling other solutions as well i used several other in built functions but they also seems to throw an error

Comment: Yeah, it seems like its something about how the barcode scanner provides input to the GUI.